# Fetch Core Data ManageObject sorting from last item

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, fetch

I want to fetch all items from Core Data, but sorted from lastest to oldest. My Entity "Dice" has attribute "timestamp" of type Date.

This is how I save and fetch:

```
class func saveResults(_ withResults: Int) -> Bool {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Dice", in: context)
    let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    let date = Date()

    manageObject.setValue(withResults, forKey: "result")
    manageObject.setValue(date, forKey: "timestamp")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}

class func fetchObject() -> [Dice]? {
    let context = getContext()
    var dices:[Dice]? = nil

    do {
        dices = try context.fetch(Dice.fetchRequest())
        return dices
    } catch {
        return dices
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to sort it. All solutions are confusing and showing the sort from old to new.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an appropriate sort descriptor.

I recommend to make the function `throw` and hand over the error.

```
class func fetchObject() throws -> [Dice] {
    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Dice> = Dice.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)]
    return try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
}
```

Note: The `fetch` operation returns `[Dice]`. A type cast is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
class func fetchObject() -> [Dice]? {
            var dices:[Dice]? = nil
            let context = getContext()
            let fetchDice: NSFetchRequest<Dice> = Dice.fetchRequest()
            let sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)]
            fetchDice.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor
            do
            {
                dices = try context.fetch(fetchDice) 
                return dices
            }catch(let error) {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return dices
            }
   }
```

Comment: This solution works. No need to cast as [Dice]. Thanks